# Performance impact of class inheritance

Tags: c#, performance

So, this may seem like a very odd question for many, but here it is:

Say you have an abstract class "Object" with an abstract method doStuff() which 10.000 classes inherit from.

Then in another class you have an "Object" dictionary with 100 random objects of the "Object" type in it. You call doStuff() on them.

Does the amount of **classes** have any performance impact? How does the executable find which class to execute the method of? Is that a jumptable, a pointertable, the equivalent logic of a huge switch-case, ..?

If it has any performance impact, are there ways to structure your code differently to eliminate this problem?

I feel I am really overthinking this.

Comment: in .Net word, each object carries on some extra information, i.e not only the members that the programmer write in the class that the object is an instance of. At runtime, these extra informations are used (not only) to call the correct  `DoStuff` method. so actually, having 2 or 2000 classes inheriting from object does not make any difference in resolving the correct method to invoke

Answer (score 1):

There is no noticeable performance impact when you call `doStuff`.

At runtime, the type of object you are calling `doStuff` on is known *for sure*. At compile time you'd need a giant switch statement because you don't know the type. CLR sees that you are trying to call `doStuff` on `Subclass0679`, goes into that class, and invokes the method. Simple as that.

Think about it this way. `ToString()` is declared in `Object` and *all* classes inherit `Object`. When you call `ToString()` on something, is it really slow? No.

Comment: Just wanted to point out again that my question has the C# tag, not the java tag. But because of the similarities I have no trouble believing it is the same there (still, please correct your answer for others). Also, could you elaborate on the class loader please?

Comment: @uncanny Oops! But it's basically the same in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The number of derived classes can have some impact.

In particular, with ten thousand derived classes and only 100 objects, chances are pretty good that each call to `doStuff` will actually be to a unique function, separate from the others. That means your cache won't be very effective.

This is a fairly unrealistic scenario though. A collection that could be any one of ten thousand different derived classes is unlikely to ever arise in actual practice.

To put this in perspective, .NET (in its entirety) consists of about nine thousand nine hundred classes. A decent sized application could easily add the hundred or so more needed to get to ten thousand--but you're talking about a collection that could include *anything* in .NET, plus anything in your application. I find it difficult to imagine a situation in which this is likely to make sense.

Comment: Easy example: A big game where every item has totally unique features and therefore specific code to run. In this case there comes the question though not to switch to a dictionary of function pointers that all point to functions in a single class. Item parameters would need to be separated then, so it also has its drawbacks

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking this out of curiosity as a hypothetical question, then fair enough.

However, if you're trying to prematurely optimise some code and this is the level of decisions you're making, I would highly recommend you concentrate on making your code work first and then use a profiler to identify hotspots as areas to optimise.

Also, super optimised code is usually far less readable and maintainable.

Unless your code is a game engine or perform some enormous calculation, then does it really need to be so optimised? If the code communicates with the outside world at all - network, disk, db etc - then that latency will completely dwarf any imperceptible difference in timing because of using inheritance.

Comment: Funnily enough, it is indeed for a game engine/framework that is specifically designed to handle the most absurd loads

Comment: I would still expect the algorithms themselves to be more important than using inheritance vs a dictionary. Using techniques such as precalculating values  or designing algorithms to keep value pieces of data in the processor cache etc. Good luck!!